# Why doesn't Python find the method in WSDL file?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've written a piece of code in Python to call SOAP API using wsdl url.
Python throws an error saying:

```
raise RuntimeError('Operation %s not found in WSDL: '
RuntimeError: Operation VerifyConsumerIsAliveRequest not found in WSDL: Service/Port 
Type: ('VerificationService', 'DefaultEndpoint')
```

I double-checked it and there's such a method as VerifyConsumerIsAliveRequest in wsdl url.

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
import base64

# Define the SOAP service endpoint URL
service_url = 'https://demo.krd.pl/Rastin/v2/Verification.svc?singleWsdl'

# Create the SOAP client
client = SoapClient(wsdl=service_url)

# Set the SOAP headers for authorization
username = 'placeholder'
password = 'placeholder'
authorization = base64.b64encode(f'{username}:{password}'.encode()).decode()
client.http_headers = {'Authorization': f'Basic {authorization}'}

# Set the SOAP request parameters
consumer_identity_number = 'placeholder'
first_name = 'placeholder'
surname = 'placeholder'

# Make the SOAP request
response = client.VerifyConsumerIsAlive(
    ConsumerIdentityNumber=consumer_identity_number,
    FirstName=first_name,
    Surname=surname
)

# Process the SOAP response
if response:
    result = response.get('VerifyConsumerIsAliveResult')
    print(result)
else:
    print('No response received.')
```

I'm racking my brains trying to get to know the cause of the error.
Got any idea?